# Getting rid of Django's default_permissions by default

Tags: python, django, django-models

In the Django project I work on, the built in `('add', 'change', 'delete')` permissions are next to useless for us, and only confuse our users in forms; we don't use the Django admin, it often doesn't make much sense for us to have three permissions instead of one `edit` permission, and our models are more granular than the objects we want to assign permissions to (as a made-up example, it doesn't make sense to have seperate permissions for an `Invoice` and an `InvoiceLine` - they're conceptually the same thing).

Anyway, at the moment I'm accomplishing this by subclassing each model from a custom abstract base model which has `default_permissions = ()` in it's `Meta`, plus some ugly hacks to make the permissions from third-party models go away. Is there any way I can make Django not create those three permissions by default?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the admin then just don't bother about the default permissions. They are not enforced by default anywhere else. Feel free to create your own [Permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#permission) and check that the user has this in your edit views, with [permission_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) for function views and [PermissionRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin) for class based view (and Django>1.9).

Comment: We don't use the admin, but we _do_ need to give administrative users a way to edit other users' permissions, and at the moment they're looking at a `MultipleSelect` of over 300 options when less than 30 are relevant.

Comment: You could override the AdminForm for your users and limit the queryset for permissions. Or you could create a Group and assign users membership to that, there's no decorator or mixin to check for group membership but it's very easily created.

Comment: I thought about filtering on the `ModelForm` (as I mentioned, we're not using the admin, so no `AdminForm`), but decided against it as the filter would have got a little complicated to avoid hiding permissions we _do_ want. But if the hacks I mentioned in the question turn out to cause us problems, I might have to go down that route.

Comment: Can you show your form and view code where you handle permissions?